# Changing MainPage between AppShell and NagivationPage breaks app screen

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I found an issue of Xamarin.Forms 4.0 on Changing MainPage between AppShell and NagivationPage.

It is very easy to reproduce the issue.

1) Create a new Xamarin.Forms 4.0 solution with AppShell Template at Visual Studio 2019.

2) Add a Content Page into Views folder (LoginPage.xaml)

3) Change MainPage at App.xaml.cs like this;

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DependencyService.Register<MockDataStore>();
        //MainPage = new AppShell();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Views.LoginPage());
    }
```

4) Change MainPage in LoginPage like this (I added a Button at LoginPage.xaml);

```
    private void LoginButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage = new AppShell();
    }
```

5) Add a MenuItem at AppShell and Add MenuItem Click event handler like this;

```
private void LogoutMenuItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Views.LoginPage());
}
```

6) Bulid and run the app

7) “Login and Logout” action makes app screen broken like the attached screen shot.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/skbgti26v6m2x3u/Screenshot_20190627-181115.png?dl=0

App MainPage is changed like this;

> NavigationPage(new Views.LoginPage()) => new AppShell() =>
>   NavigationPage(new Views.LoginPage()).

It is common pattern to implement Login function and I am regarding it may be a XF bug.

My testing environment is Visual Studio 2019 on Windows 10 Pro and I updated XF 4.0 up to date.

Is there any solution or workaround to solve the issue?

Best regards.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues

Answer (score 0):

Good job! Fill out an issue in the [Xamarin Forms Github](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms) so they can fix it